# Why is it not possible to assign a reference to a class to a class variable?

Tags: python, class

Pretty much what the title says but I will put some example code to clarify.
I would like to know why I can assign Repair, a reference to the class, to an instance variable but not to a class variable

```
class NotWorkingDefinitions:  
    # This will give unresolved reference
    a = Repair


class WorkingDefitinions:
    def __init__(self):
        # This is fine
        self.a = Repair


class Repair():
    def __init__(self):
        whatever = 10

    def dosmt(self):
         print("staring at a wall")
```

EDIT: The full answer is given over the different comments. It wasn't about not being able to assign to a class variable. It is just that class variables are immediately resolved and instance variables are not. The latter makes that defining Repair() class after WorkingDefinitions is not an issue.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the error here: `NameError: name 'Repair' is not defined`. The script is evaluated top-to-bottom, so `class NotWorkingDefinitions:` needs to come _after_ `Repair()` is defined.

Comment: But then, why does the instance variable case not have this same issue? Is it because with instance variables, it is evaluated lazy (so not until the class is actually instantiated)?

Comment: https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/20/python-class-attributes-are-evaluated-on-declaration.html Correct.

Comment: I wouldn't use lazy in this case. Instance attributes lives withing the instance and will be evaluated during initiation. In first case you declared attribute on class level that got evaluated instantly.

Comment: @СергейНиколаевич Yeah, that's probably a better distinction to make.

Answer (score 1):

The above code works if you move `Repair` to the top. The content of a class is evaluated from top to bottom, so any referenced classes must be defined before actually referencing them.

An example that explores this a bit more in terms of runtime and load-time could be:

```
# this will not work because the B class is referenced before definition
class A(object):
    b_class = B

class B(object):
    pass
```

Alternatively,

```
# this will work because B is defined first and used later
class B(object):
    pass

class A(object):
    b_class = B
```

But both of the examples above do not have a runtime-specific behavior. If instead you wanted `A` to use `B` and you had a *really* good reason to define `A` first, then you could get away with

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # bind the B class to each instance of A
        self.b_class = B

class B(object):
    pass

a = A()
a.b_class
> __main__.B
```

But the short answer is **you must define a variable before using it** and when you bind a variable directly to a class (in the class definition, not a method) it must be defined.

Answer (score 0):

The full answer is given over the different comments. It is not about not being able to assign to a class variable. It is that class variables are immediately evaluated and instance variables are not. Instance variables will be evaluated during initiation. The latter makes that defining Repair() class after WorkingDefinitions is not an issue.